# Вопрос по защите приложения

Tags: java, android, защита, декомпиляция

1. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то определить в коде приложения, что его пытается декомпилировать декомпилятор, и в этом случае запустить функцию, в которой будет качаться, допустим, 1ТБ информации?
2. Или декомпилятор ничего не скачивает, даже если в логике приложения это есть?
3. Есть ли смысл запихивать в приложение ложный код, который нигде не используется, если есть, то какой примерно объём кода в МБ должен быть в приложении, чтобы отсечь хотя бы слабые машины от декомпила. 
   Благодарю.

Comment: Декомпилятор не исполняет приложение, соответственно "качать" ничего он не будет. Ложный код будет легко отсечен построением графа вызовов, который для dex, в целом, строится легко. И декомпилер не столь ресурсоемок, чтобы объем кода на него значимо влиял

Comment: Код приложения - это файлы. Декомпилятор не будет пытаться запустить ваш код. Насчет объёма ненужного кода в мегабайтах - это смотря насколько вам плевать на пользователей приложения. Можно гигабайт такого кода натолкать - тогда проблем не будет, так как нет пользователей -> нет интереса к приложению -> никто не будет его декомпилить. Отсечь неиспользуемый код при желании, вероятно, будет несложно, так что только если радикально, с 1ГБ...

Comment: Приложение само себя защитить не может. Не тратьте на это время. Защищайте данные, уникальные алгоритмы и т.п.

Comment: Комментарии не могу писать из-за рейтинга, а так в интернете много статей про обфускацию. Также не ленитесь читать, на английском [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827935/how-to-protect-or-secure-java-code-from-decompiling) задавали такие же вопросы.

Comment: Если вы сами смотрели вашу ссылку, то можете выделить оттуда основные мысли и перенести в ваш ответ. Это не запрещено и даже наоборот, будет намного полезней чем ваш текущий ответ-ссылка.

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вообще никак нельзя определить, что приложение декомпилируется. Декомпилятор работает с кодом как с *потоком байтов*, а не исполняемой сущностью.
2. Ничего. См. ответ 1.
3. Это не поможет. Большинство декомпиляторов читают байт-код по частям, поэтому переполнить стак путём загрузки лишнего кода не получится. Тем более, как сказали выше, такие "пустышки" легко определяются.

Хотите защитить приложение? [Обфусцируйте][1] его. На Android, в частности, есть утилита [ProGuard][2].

[1] - [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обфускация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%84%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

[2] - https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/112833/

Comment: по всем трем пунктам согласен с автором ответа, но обфускацию настоятельно не рекомендую. во-первых, есть ненулевая вероятность, что прошедший через обфускатор код вообще не будет работать (например, могут неверно обрабатываться вызовы класса по имени). во-вторых, подобный код сложнее поддерживать, особенно при частых деплоях и коротких циклах android-разработки. рекомендую вообще не заморачиваться с кодом клиента, он легко вскрывается. просто перенесите наиболее важные алгоритмы и значимый код на сервер и вызывайте их по API.

Comment: @Trashbox Bobylev Благодарю за ответ. На счёт первого пункта интуитивно был уверен, что так и происходит, как написали Вы.
А по поводу 3-го пункта, а что если создать большую цепь функций и классов, которые используются в самом приложении, но смысла от них нет, это только для запутывания взломщиков?
На счёт обфуксаторов знаю, но вроде любой код пропущенный через любой обфуксатор успешно декомпилируется?

Comment: @Dmitry Maslennikov Благодарю за ответ. В моём случае логику нельзя выносить из приложения на сервер, так как оно должно работать без подключения к интернет.

Comment: @lamerboy Успешно, конечно, но результат, мягко говоря, будет декомпилировщику бесполезен :D.

Comment: @lamerboy если без подключения к интернету, то здесь можно только увеличить трудозатраты на обратный инжиниринг (декомпиляцию и т.д.). вопрос в том, что при этом также пропорционально будут увеличиваться ваши трудозатраты на поддержку приложения. насколько сильно это нужно - решайте сами.

Answer (score 2):

Лучшая защита - не храните на мобильном устройстве логику, алгоритмы и важные данные.

Comment: Согласен с Вами, но в конкретно этом случае приложение должно работать без подключения к интернет. Но благодарю за ответ.